# Prove that $\frac{\left(6x-3-2x^3\right)}{4x\:-\:2}\:$ is $\theta \cdot \left(x^2\right)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

> I need to prove that $\frac{6x-3-2x^3}{4x\:-\:2}\:$ is $\theta \cdot \left(x^2\right)$.

They way I tried doing this was:

At first, I tried solving for $O({x^2})$

$$\frac{\left(6x-3-2x^3\right)}{4x\:-\:2}\:\le \frac{6x}{4x}\ \le \frac{6}{4} \le \frac{6x^2}{4} 
$$

Then I tried solving for $\Omega(x^2)$:

$$\frac{\left(6x-3-2x^3\right)}{4x\:-\:2}\:\ge \frac{\left(6x^3-3x^3-2x^3\right)}{4x\:-\:2}\: \ge \frac{x^3}{4x} \le \frac{1x^2}{4} 
$$

I don't think I did this in a right way. I'm kinda lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prove $f(n)=\theta (g(n))$, prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ is a constant.

 Here $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\frac{6x-3-2x^3}{4x-2}}{x^2}=-1/2$$
So $f(x)=\theta(g(x))$